# Size of NSString - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Is there a limit as far as NSString is concerned ?? I am using the following lines of code to read the contents of file `edit.txt` but `saveString` is not able to contain all of the contents of my `.txt` file.

```
NSString *savedDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

//NSString *savedeDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *saveFilePath = [savedDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root"];
saveFilePath = [saveFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:savedName];
saveFilePath = [saveFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"edit.txt"];
NSString *saveString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:saveFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; 
NSLog(@"saveString is :: %@ savedSpaceName : %@ savefilepath : %@ ", saveString, savedName, saveFilePath);
```

Is there an issue with the size of NSString ?? I am unable to figure it out. Can someone provide me an explaination or help me to figure it out. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: are you sure the file exists?

Comment: Does saveString contain some of your text, or none of your text?

Comment: What output are you getting??

Comment: The length of `NSString` is limited by `NSUIntegerMax`, a 32-bit value. Is your file really over 4Gb?

Comment: it contains only some of my text. Yes, the file does exists .. and it is `not empty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the hard limit for NSString would be `NSUIntegerMax` characters, since NSString's index and size-related methods return an NSUInteger. Since all devices currently capable of running `iOS` are 32 bit, this means `NSUIntegerMax` is 2^32 - 1 and `NSString` can hold a little over 4.2 billion characters.

As far as I know, the practical limit is much smaller - on an iOS device especially, you'll run out of memory long before you hit any hard limit in NSString.

So your problem is something else!!!

Comment: what might the problem be then ?? I am getting only some of my test to be NSLogged.

Comment: Try putting your file directly in the Documents Directory rather than putting it inside a Root directory, I did so!!!

Comment: but my app is such that it requires a separate Root directory. but I'll try putting it in the Documents Directory too.

Comment: Your file might be containing a character something like endOfFile character or so, that's why it might be stoping from there...

Comment: hmm .. now it is giving me the correct value. But why is it happening to be wrong if I use a Root directory ??

Comment: Same problem accuring with me when I put it inside a Root Directory, can't find any problem, any ways can you please mark my answer right if it was helpful to you!! Thanks !!!

Comment: It was helpful but did not help me sort out the error .. lol .. I can upvote right now